# Preferred way to initialize base class members (c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

I have a base class:

```
class Base {
protected:
    int m_a;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}
```

And a derived class(es)

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived(int a);
}
```

The base class is abstract, so only derived classes can be created.
How is the better way to implement the derived Ctor?

```
Derived::Derived(int a) : Base(a) {}
Base::Base(int a) : m_a(a) {}
```

Or

```
Derived::Derived(int a) { m_a = a;}
Base::Base(){}
```

Is it better to remove the member from Base constructor, since it cannot be created alone, OR to keep it on the Base constructor to stay the assignment for him?

Comment: What kind of "better" do you have in mind? Anyway, the first violated guideline is the use of `protected` data members. Make that `private` and the rest follows.

Comment: it's more of an opinion based. I'd always prefer to follow first way because 1. all `Base` class logic remains in `Base` class; 2. it's the only way if `m_a` is `const`

Comment: Don't use protected data members. Stroustrup says it was a mistake to ever have them in the language. All data should be private. See how thete's only one way to do things now? That's even before we start talking about const and non-copyable data and move semantics and all that weird and wonderful stuff.

Comment: @n.m. - what do you mean by "all data should be private"? If I have some derived methods that need to use a protected member - would you prefer getters and setters to this member, instead of doing it protected? Will the getters and setters be protected too?

Comment: "would you prefer getters and setters" no, I would pretty much prefer a *redesign*. A class should not be defined in terms of what it *has*, but rather what it *does*. Getters and setters are sort of ok as a stopgap measure while you redesign. They should be protected of course.

Comment: @n.m. - I want to ask about a general case, when derived classes need to use/change a member of the base class. What will you do?
1. Declare this member on each derived? 2. Use getters and setters? 3. make it private? 4. Create special methods for the purpose you need the access?

Comment: "need to use/change a member of the base class" I wouldn't specify the problem in these terms in the first place. Why should a derived class ever know what data members the base class has, much less want or need to change them?

Comment: If a base class has a member that every derived class need to use, so we have 2 options: 1. declare the member in every derived class. 2. declare it once in the base class, and we won't need to declare it multiple times on the derived classes. Moreover, we cannot implement common functionality on the base class with this member - if it is not declared on the base class.

Comment: [Here's the authoritative quotation](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=PSUNAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA604&dq=%22declaring+data+members+protected+is+usually+a+design+error%22&pg=PA604&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22declaring%20data%20members%20protected%20is%20usually%20a%20design%20error%22&f=false). I'm afraid these comments are not a good place to discuss it. Perhaps if you post a question about this paragraph...

Comment: He does say it is protected ***data*** members that are the issue. Having protected *methods*, and having protected base methods is OK. Having getters and setters is agreed not good design, but I'm sure even @n.m. has been caught doing it occasionally :-) Personally I could put a strong argument for protected const member data, i.e. getter only, but why bother writing a getter for const?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first solution- giving the base class an explicit constructor -  is preferable as general pattern:

- it avoids other classes inherited from Base forgetting to initialize m_a. Instead, the signature of the class indicates initialization is required.
- if multiple classes inherit from base, and initialization is more complex (e.g. a range check) , this code - and policy - is not distributed over multiple derived classes
- if m_a is immutable, constructor initialization is required
- derived classes might have more than one CTor, more places to forget

Only downside: a little more typing - as long as you don't count the additional "I'm a little lazy today so don't forget to init m_a in all derived classes constructors"

The "signature announces the requirements" is IMO sufficient to make this the default pattern, so is "the other way requires making m_a protected", as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer :

```
Derived::Derived(int a) : Base(a) {}
Base::Base(int a) : m_a(a) {}
```

By this way you make your code more encapsulated and `Base` members took care about its init list, there can be some more init logic in base class constructor depending on m_a instead of just initing `m_a`. In this case you pass initial value to your base constructor and then derived class in his constructor has initialized constructor of base class.

You should try to pass init values to your `Base` class, imagine you have 5 `Derived` classes and you need to init base class at all of yours derived ctors.